# How to choose a good model for classification?

Tags: neural-networks, logistic, classification

I have some data that I would like to use to do some predictions. The data is some value over time and I want to predict the occurrence or not of some behavior. So for example I have the data `d_t1`, `d_t2`, `d_t3`, `d_t4` and treating these as four features I would like a binary classification:  `A happens`,`A does not happen`.

Now, the first thing that came to my mind was ***logistic regression*** but then I found that LR applies to problems were the data can be linearly separable. I can't be sure my data is like this.

So how can I choose a good model for this binary classification?

Comment: `LR applies to problems were the data can be linearly separable` false, LR doesn't separate anything, you may be thinking of SVM. Also, LR is not a classification model, it is a probabilistic model.